# storing values in string during recursion

Tags: c++, recursion

I want to store the values produced by a recursive function in a string, but I am not sure how to keep after each iteration of the loop. Im not necessarily looking for you to solve it particular to the attached code, but I figured it would give it some context. Simply commenting resources where I can learn this is, of course, welcome. 
Thanks

```
int HailstoneNumbers(int N)
{
    vector <char> sequence;
    static int c;

    cout << N << " ";

    if (N == 1 && c == 0) {

        // N is initially 1.
        return c;
    }
    else if (N == 1 && c != 0) {

        // N is reduced to 1.
        c++;
        return c;
    }
    else if (N % 2 == 0) {

        // If N is Even.
        c++;
        HailstoneNumbers(N / 2);
    }
    else if (N % 2 != 0) {

        // N is Odd.
        c++;
        HailstoneNumbers(3 * N + 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hint: You don't want the sequence to be automatically destructed every time this function returns.

Comment: Huh. I've never heard the Collatz Conjecture sequence called "Hailstone" before. I'd advise looking up C++ collatz examples. In 99% of cases, if you have a `static` variable in your recursion, it means you're trying to force the recursion the wrong way.

Comment: first it seems your recursive calls need to be `return HailstoneNumbers...` second pass the vector by reference

Answer (score 2):

If you want to store `N` values, you can store them in a vector as follows

```
int HailstoneNumbers(int N, vector<int>& sequence)
{
    int c;

    sequence.push_back(N);

    if (N == 1 && c == 0) {

        // N is initially 1.
        return c;
    }
    else if (N == 1 && c != 0) {

        // N is reduced to 1.
        c++;
        return c;
    }
    else if (N % 2 == 0) {

        // If N is Even.
        c++;
        HailstoneNumbers(N / 2, sequence);
    }
    else if (N % 2 != 0) {

        // N is Odd.
        c++;
        HailstoneNumbers(3 * N + 1, sequence);
    }
}
```

declare a vector before calling your function as `vector<int> sequence;` then call your function using your `N` and this vector